# PDF JavaScript: Insert value of variable into form field

Tags: javascript, variables, pdf

I have a PDF with JavaScipt, all end users running Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I have successfully figure out how to get it to fill a form field with values from other form fields:

```
// Assuming FormFieldB has a value of "somewhere" and FormFieldA is a text box

this.getField("FormFieldA").value = "Fills a sentence and adds a string from " + this.getField("FormFieldB").value + " successfully.";

// This fills the box with "Fills a sentence and adds a string from somewhere successfully.
```

But what I'm trying to do is basically the same thing but I'm trying to take the value of a **variable** and add it into the form field.

```
var my_variable = "somewhere";

this.getField("FormFieldA").value = "Fills a sentence and adds a string from <How do I insert from my_variable> successfully";

// I want it do write the same example sentence as before
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the strings...

```
var my_variable = "somewhere";

this.getField("FormFieldA").value = "Fills a sentence and adds a string from "+my_variable+" successfully";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using ES6 syntax you can use it this way:

```
let my_variable = "somewhere";
this.getField("FormFieldA").value = `Fills a sentence and adds a string from ${my_variable} successfully`;
```

" ` " is the backtick/string literal operator introduced in ES6 it stands just before the 1 key.

Comment: Amit, it seems I’m not setup for that as I get syntax errors. Any other solutions?